# Qt Qt5Core.dll compilation failed

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I made a program using Qt (5.6) and QtCreator(3.6.1). 
This program works properly when I start it from QtCreator, but when I try to use the .exe, an error occur : "The procedure entry point ?left@QString@@QBE?AV1@H@Z not found in dynamics links library Qt5Core.dll" (or something like this, i'm actually traducting a French error).

I put Qt5Core.dll, libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll file in the same folder.
I checked-up on the net, but everyone want to create a "commercial executable file". To do so, they have to compile Qt statically. That is not really something I would like to do. So I'm wondering if there is a way to not have this error? Am I missing a dll?

Thanks for all!

EDIT :

My .PRO:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = EasyDelete
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mytree.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    deletefile.cpp

HEADERS  += \
    mytree.h \
    mainwindow.h \
    deletefile.h
```

**Problem Solved :** 
I just needed Qt5Gui.dll and Qt5Widgets.dll in the folder and it worked!

Comment: Is it a debug or release executable that you built? If it's debug, you need different dlls. Also could you put the complete error, even in French?

Comment: This is a release version. :) and the error is : ""Le point d'entrée de procédure ?left@QString@@QBE?AV1@H@Z est introuvable dans la bibliothèque de liens dynamiques Qt5Core.dll. " in french

Comment: This is very strange, could you post your .pro file?

Comment: I think you need to add `CONFIG += qt` on top of your file.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. The error is still here. :/ If I remove the Qt5core.dll The same message occur only with _ZN10QArrayData10deallocateEPS_jj instead of ?left@QString@@QBE?AV1@H@Z

Comment: OK!!! Found it!

Comment: Cool, what was the problem?

Comment: I compiled in Debug mode, and errors were easier to understand (Qt5Widgetsd.dll is missing, Qt5Guid.dll is missing. ) In fact, i needed QWidgets.dll and QtGui.dll too in the folder to make it works! But thanks a lot! :)